# Accessing imported data in google appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have managed to create a data model, and in doing so import data variables and values from my googlespreadsheets (by clicking on 'import data from sheet'). My table is of the form:

table = {"age": {15,22}, "name": {"ted", "sally"}, "surname":{"anderson","medina"}}

I would like to have a table that uploads this on a page, and then I can click on each row which would then open up another page and I could edit the contents

I open a new page and drag a table in and link it to my data model. However, it only shows the variable titles and not the actual data. How can I get the data to automatically upload into the table?

I read alot of the tutorials but they all assume I want to start with only headers, and then manually input the data to create a data entry table. However, my table updates automatically in googlesheets, so I would like to import it to appmaker, and then have the ability to click on each row and add notes/edits. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

At this time App Maker doesn't support spreadsheets as data backend. You'll need first import all data to App Maker's models and then play with it in deployed application. You can find all pieces of the puzzle in Vendor Ratings template:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/vendor-rating/

Comment: thanks for this - pretty much identical to what I am trying to do. It would be nice to use a spreadsheet as a backend though, with the app automatically updating with the spreadsheet.. my spreadsheet reads my emails and extracts data into a table. would be great if my app updated as my emails came in.. cheers for the response

Comment: If you refuse from storing spreadsheet data in two places (spreadsheet itself and AM), then I think you can achieve desired result with combination of Calculated Datasource (to read data from spreadsheet using SpreadsheetApp and bind it to AM widgets) and 'google.script.run.serverFunctionToEditSpreadsheet'.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual data won't come up in your editor view, only when you preview it.

It seems to me that you could make this using an embedded Google sheet in your page.

Ex:
-drag an html block on the page
-set the content to something like:

```
<iframe src="[link to your google sheet]" height="1380" width="1100"></iframe>
```

*get the embed link from 'Publish to the Web'

Hope that helps, it might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: It does help, thanks. I managed to view the data from my SS in the preview mode. I did this by selecting the model database I made for the table i dragged in, and then clicking on the individual fields and binding them to the actual values in the property editor